# Invalid reads, writes and frees

Tags: c, valgrind

I got a lot of write, read and free errors. I don't know where is mistake. If someone could help me out with this I'd be grateful. Here is log from valgrind: 
http://pastebin.com/TR4Ts73Y

```
void deleteElement(element* node) {
element* child;
if (node == NULL)
    return;

free(node->name);

if (node->text != NULL)
    free(node->text);

child = node->firstChild;
while(child != NULL)
{
    deleteElement(child);
    child = child->nextSibling;
}

free(node);
}
```

If you need more functions feel free to ask for.

Comment: Try to share a full program, preferably reduced to the core of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this will be kinda helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011990/c-programming-linked-lists-delete-node-at-position-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the code in the question is here:

```
while(child != NULL)
{
    deleteElement(child); // this calls free on child
    child = child->nextSibling; // OOPS, child has been freed
}
```

Here you destroy `child` and then immediately try to use it again. You need an extra variable.

```
while(child != NULL)
{
    element* nodeToDelete = child;
    child = child->nextSibling;
    deleteElement(nodeToDelete);
}
```

There may be other errors in your complete program, but that's the obvious one that can be detected in the code excerpt that you posted.

Comment: Thanks! Is it somehow possible to send you the rest of the code? I can't share it publicly so...

Comment: I've put there other functions

Comment: If you can't post them here, then we can't help. I rolled back the question. I think I answered the question that you asked. If you have further problems, make that further questions.